# Deleting rows conditionally in python with dates

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I would like to standardize my dataframe making it start and end at a precise date but i can't find the solution...
I am dealing with a timeseries so it is crucial I have everything starting and ending on the same day.

I have tried several piece of code including code from stackvoerflow but nothing works.

Right now I just want rows that are between 01/01/2010 and 31/12/2017 this is the code I have so far:

```
df=pd.read_csv("AREX.csv", sep = ";")
df[~df['Date'].isin(pd.date_range(start='20100101', end='20171231'))]        
print(df)
df.drop(["Open","High","Low","Volume","Open interest"],axis = 1, inplace=True)
print(df)
```

But it does not affect the number of rows it only drops the column I ask it to.

Does anyone has any idea on how to fix this?

Thank you in advance for any piece of advice you can give me!

Comment: Have to assign back ... `df = df[~df['Date'].isin(pd.date_range(start='20100101', end='20171231'))]   `

Comment: No I tried that earlier and it does not work either... :/ But thank you for the input :)

Comment: Look, there are several things that could be happening. First of all, is `Date` an actual datetime dtype column ? Second, you definitely have to assign back, otherwise your code is doing nothing. Third, instead of using `pd.date_range`, use `(df.Date <= '2017-12-31)` & (df.Date >= '2010-01-01)`

Comment: Thank you so much for your help ! So part of it works now, it starts at 2010 but does not stop as 2017 I'll need to figure out a solution.
here is the chnage I have made
`df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df = df[~df['Date'].isin(df.Date <= '2017-12-31') & (df.Date >= '2010-01-01')]`

Thank you @RafaelC

Comment: Gregoire, there's no such thing as `isin` in this case. Use just `df[df.Date <= '2017-12-31') & (df.Date >= '2010-01-01')]`. Also, make sure to do `df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])` first to ensure this is a datetime clumn

Comment: Thank you for all the advice and solution ! I have put it my loop and it works perfectly now ! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so thanks to @RafaelC here is the answer to my problem.

```
def concatenate(indir="../Equity_Merton", outfile = "../Merged.csv"):
    os.chdir(indir)    
    fileList = glob.glob("*.csv")
    ticker = []
    main_df = pd.DataFrame()

    for filename in fileList:
        print(filename)
        df=pd.read_csv(filename, sep = ";")
        ticker.append(df)
        df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
        df = df[(df.Date <= '2017-12-31') & (df.Date >= '2010-01-01')]
        df.set_index("Date", inplace=True)     
        df.rename(columns = {"Close": filename[0:len(filename) - 4]}, inplace = True)
        df.drop(["Open","High","Low","Volume","Open interest"],axis = 1, inplace=True)

        if main_df.empty:
            main_df = df
        else:
            main_df = main_df.join(df, how='outer')

#        main_df = main_df.dropna(axis = 0, how="any")
        main_df.sort_index(axis=0, level=None, ascending=False, inplace=True, kind='quicksort', na_position='last')

    print(main_df.head())
    main_df.to_csv('Merton_Merged.csv')         
    shutil.move("Merton_Merged.csv", "../Merton_Merged.csv")
```

Thank you for your help!!